# azurerm_key_vault_access_policy is getting created after successful deployment with azurerm provider 2.99.0

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

I am trying to create access policy for KV in different state but needed for APIM identity, User managed identity

It is creating the access policy successfully and on the next run it is creating again, as it is already present in terraform state but recreating it again

Answer (score 0):

> We tried to provision **azurerm_key_vault_access_policy** multiple times but the state not allowing to provision a new policy every time with the updated azure provider.

Here I tried to replicate the scenario and checked if I might get the error form my side as well, but it doesn't.

My **main.tf** file:

```
provider  "azurerm" {

features {

key_vault {

purge_soft_delete_on_destroy  =  true

recover_soft_deleted_key_vaults  =  true

}

}

}

  

data  "azurerm_client_config"  "current" {}

  

resource  "azurerm_resource_group"  "example" {

name  =  "demorgvk"

location  =  "East US"

}

  

resource  "azuread_application"  "example" {

display_name  =  "demoappvk"

}

  

resource  "azuread_service_principal"  "example" {

application_id  =  azuread_application.example.application_id

app_role_assignment_required  =  false

}

  

resource  "azurerm_key_vault"  "example" {

name  =  "examplekeyvaultvk"

location  =  azurerm_resource_group.example.location

resource_group_name  =  azurerm_resource_group.example.name

enabled_for_disk_encryption  =  true

tenant_id  =  data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id

soft_delete_retention_days  =  7

purge_protection_enabled  =  false

  

sku_name  =  "standard"

  

access_policy {

tenant_id  =  data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id

object_id  =  data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

  

key_permissions  =  [

"Get",

]

  

secret_permissions  =  [

"Get",

]

  

storage_permissions  =  [

"Get",

]

}

}
   
  

resource  "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy"  "example-principal" {

key_vault_id  =  azurerm_key_vault.example.id

tenant_id  =  data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id

object_id  =  azuread_service_principal.example.object_id

  

key_permissions  =  [

"Get", "List", "Encrypt", "Decrypt"

]

}
```

The cause for error you're facing might have some reasons.

1. State file might be Tainted.
2. Check the permissions of resource groups, the access policy & the service principal that runs the terraform and make sure we have unique name for access policy.
3. Use the syntax mentioned below for resource which provision every time we make a run command.

   **lifecycle {

   prevent_destroy = true

   }**

This prevents the destroying of resource.

**Output:**

1st run `terraform_plan`:

[image]

1st run `terraform_apply`:

[image]

[image]

2nd run **`terraform_plan`**

[image]

Also check with azurerm_key_vault_access_policy saved in the state file should not be modified at the while execution run.

[image]

By following all the steps mentioned we can overcome the issue of reprovisioning of resource at every run time.

Comment: Unfortunately, It is still the same, @Vinay Kumar, what provider version are you using? I am using 2.99.0

Comment: @chandrashekhar Please use the latest version of provider 3.61.0 version.

Comment: It worked with3.72.0, Thanks Vinay